# Make 8 Ajax calls into 1

Tags: php, javascript

So i have a picture gallery with eight categories. Each category has 400+ images, these subcategories are called there by AJAX. I also have a pagination system in the subcategories. Currently i have 8 ajax calls, which is useless, so i'd like to shrink them into one by giving 2 arguements: 'lap' which tells it which page it's on, if lap == 0 or null it gives the normal page, else it gives oldal+?page= + lap. 'Oldal' is the second arguement, it is used at the first category selection where it tells the browser which php file to open(kepek_kat1.php or kepek_kat2 ... kepek_kat8.php). 'Oldal' works great with opening the categories, going into the subcategories, but the pagination doesn't work. 
Here is my code of the 8 caregories:

```
  <div id="kepek">
    <div class="kepkat"><a href="#amator" onclick="mutikat(null,'../php/kepek_kat1.php');"><img src="../img/kepkat/amator.jpg" height="130px" width="90px" alt="Amatőrök"/><br/>Amatőr</a></div></div> <!-- only showing the first selection -->
```

So the first arguement is null, which gives it the page without pagination.

Here is my subcategory code:

```
echo "<div class='lapozo'><a onclick='mutikat($page, '../php/kepek_kat1.php');'  href='../html/blog.php#amator?page=$page'>$page</a></div>"; }
```

The $page is in a loop, it lists which page it is currently on, it displays the page controls.

Here is my ajax call:

```
function mutikat(lap, oldal)
{
            //create XMLHttpRequest object
            xmlHttpRequest = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? 
            new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

            //If the browser doesn't support Ajax, exit now
            if (xmlHttpRequest == null)
            return;

            if(lap == 0 || lap === 0 || lap == null )
            {
            //Initiate the XMLHttpRequest object
            xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", oldal, true);
            }
            else
            {
                xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", oldal + '?page=' +lap, true);
            }
            //Setup the callback function
            xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = StateChange;

            //Send the Ajax request to the server with the GET data
            xmlHttpRequest.send(null);
}
function StateChange()
{
            if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4)
            {
            document.getElementById('kepek').innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
            }
}
```

there are 8 ajax calls.
Please help me!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you can load 8 ajax calls asynchronously using [jQuery's $.when.then();](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) functions...

Here is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


    $.when(
        $.getScript("http://domain.com/script_one.js"),
        $.getScript("http://domain.com/script_two.js"),
        $.getScript("http://domain.com/script_three.js"),
        $.getScript("http://domain.com/script_four.js")
    ).then(

        $(function() {

            //work with downloaded scripts and their variables here

        })

    );
});
</script>
```

Comment: I am still learning jQuery, isn't there a way of doing this via pure javascript?

Comment: Probably, but it would be much uglier. I have edited the example to include jQuery and the correct jQuery calls to get started.

Comment: Okay, then i'll do it with jQuery. In the function part do i have to write the ajax call i used?

Comment: No, the getScript function is a specialized ajax query in jQuery. You can simply use $.ajax() in place of $.getScript http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: aha, so i keep my 8 ajax calls in 8 different js files and then work with them at the 'them' ?